# How to get the value of clob data which has date field and compare with timestamp in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table named masterregistry and it contains all the info and business logic in it and the data type of the colum is clob

```
desc master_registy:

id number not null,
name varchar2(100),
value clob

select value from master_registry where name='REG_DATE';
```

## o/p

11-10-17

This date is common across all the business logic, I need to query my tables which has ,

```
desc get_employee
====================
id number not null,
first_name varchar2(100),
last_name varchar2(100),
last_mod_dt timestamp
```

Now I need to get all the values from the get_employee whose last_mod_dt should be greater than the value of master_registry where name='REG_DATE'.The value in the latter table is clob data, how to fetch and compare the date of a clob data against the timestamp from another table. Please help.

Comment: If `master_registry` has three columns, and you `select *` from it, how is it possible that the output is in a single column? You may think I am paying too much attention to small details, but if we can't believe you on such small things, why should we believe anything you say?

Comment: @mathguy, thanks for pointing out the mistake, But my requirement is way too beyond from your findings, The example, which I have given is for reference. I  copy pasted only the date field, which is the actual thing I have wanted to consider. I don't want you to consider id or name. It doesn't make sense right?The eg, is to visualize how the data is there in my clob column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this.

```
SELECT *
  FROM get_employee e
 WHERE last_mod_dt > (SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (TO_CHAR (VALUE), 'DD-MM-YY')
                        FROM master_registy m
                       WHERE m.id = e.id);
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59170/2)

Note that i have used the column value directly in `TO_CHAR`. You may have to use `TRIM`,`SUBSTR` or whatever required to get ONLY the date component.